# How to get a table as user input in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to be able to turn the table on / off in my chart.
I couldn't figure out, how to get a table as user input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
display_table = input.bool(true, "Display table")
...
if barstate.islast and display_table
    var t = table.new(...)
```